# How to disable missingTranslation on generated strings

Tags: android

I have an app with two flavors:

```
productFlavors {
    full {
        applicationId "com.example.full"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.full
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Full"
    }
    demo {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.demo
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Demo"
    }
}
```

When I build the release build though, I get the "MissingTranslation" error on the generated resources. Problem is, that I cannot edit those generated files, they will be overwritten.

How can I tell lint to ignore the "MissingTranslation" error on release builds?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was almost in the error itself:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
}
```